# When is a block of a group algebra a trivial extension algebra?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modular-representation-theory

Let $B$ be a block of a group algebra. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229412/trivial-extension-of-an-algebra for the definition of a trivial extension algebra (which is always a symmetric Frobenius algebra.)

> Question: When is $B$ isomorphic (or derived equivalent) to a trivial extension algebra T(A) or even a trivial extension algebra $T(A)$ with $A$ having finite global dimension?

For example any Brauer tree algebra of multiplicity 1 is isomorphic to a trivial extension algebra but it seems for representation-infinite blocks this does not happen often. Another example is that the group algebra of the Klein four group is isomorphic to the trivial extension algebra of the group algebra of the cyclic group of order two.

I have not found a reference on this.